# Как поменять страницу редиректа при условии что пользователь зашел с определенной страницы битрикс?

Tags: php, битрикс

Пытаюсь сделать редирект после регистрации в битриксе, но есть один ньюанс!
Надо чтобы если пользователь перешел со страницы оформления заказа на страницу регистрацию и зарегистрировался, то его обратно на страницу оформления заказа кидает.
Пытался так сделать в component_epilog.php но вообще не работает, т.к. получается что он после нажатия кнопки регистрации страница перезагружается и кажется будто он перешел со страницы регистрации на страницу регистрации

```
<?


  $refer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if (strpos($refer, '/personal/order/') !== false) {
$readygo = 'yes';
} else {

$readygo = 'no';

}
if ($GLOBALS["USER"]->IsAuthorized() & $readygo=='yes')
{
LocalRedirect("/personal/order/order.php");

}

if ($GLOBALS["USER"]->IsAuthorized())
{
    if ($_REQUEST["backurl"])
        LocalRedirect($_REQUEST["backurl"]);
    else
        LocalRedirect("/personal/");
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

При переходе на страницу регистрации запоминайте в сессии реферер, а далее при завершении регистрации извлекайте из сессии URI для редиректа и делайте редирект.

Comment: а как его сделать?

Comment: Вот ссылка на курс по работе с сессиями в битриксе https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=14016